# CSS Bundling output file not generating

Tags: css, asp.net, bundling-and-minification, squishit

um   using SquishIt to bundle css in a particular folder and my code is as follows

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var stsring = Bundle.Css().Add("~/css/A.css").Add("~/css/b.css").Add("~/css/c.css").Render("~/css/AAA.css");


        return View();
    }}
```

this works without giving any errors or exceptions , but unfortunately No output file can be found . I have no idea the reason behind it , I will be  grateful if anyone can do any suggestions

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Rendering bundles inside a controller action is unorthodox to say the least.  But if you are debugging, the output file will never be created and ststring would contain several link tags (one per file).

Comment: trying to minify a folder with lot of css files , there is no other way and  it worked in release mode . thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with the output?  Do you have a hard coded reference to "~/css/AAA.css" in your view?

Comment: If I'm reading right that it worked as expected in release mode, you probably just need to add a call to .ForceRelease in the chain.  Bundling does not occur when debugging (by design)